# Edit - Can't Infer Register Because It's Behavior Does Not Match Any Supported Register Model VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga, intel-fpga

This is a branch off of a separate question I asked. I am going to explain more in depth on what I am trying to do and what it is not liking. This is a school project and doesn't need to follow standards.

I am attempting to make the SIMON game. Right now, what I am trying to do is use a switch case for levels and each level is supposed to be faster (hence different frequency dividers). The first level is supposed to be the first frequency and a pattern of LEDs is supposed to light up and disappear. Before I put in a switch case, the first level was by itself (no second level stuff) and it lit up and disappeared like it should. I also used `compare = 0` in order to compare in output to an input. (The user is supposed to flip up the switches in the light pattern they saw). This worked when the first level was by itself but now that it is in a switch case, it doesn't like `compare`. I'm not sure how to get around that in order to compare an output to an input.

The errors I am getting are similar to before:

Error (10821): HDL error at FP.vhd(75): can't infer register for "compare" because its behavior does not match any supported register model

Error (10821): HDL error at FP.vhd(75): can't infer register for "count[0]" because its behavior does not match any supported register model

Error (10821): HDL error at FP.vhd(75): can't infer register for "count[1]" because its behavior does not match any supported register model

Error (10821): HDL error at FP.vhd(75): can't infer register for "count[2]" because its behavior does not match any supported register model

Error (10822): HDL error at FP.vhd(80): couldn't implement registers for assignments on this clock edge

Error (10822): HDL error at FP.vhd(102): couldn't implement registers for assignments on this clock edge

Error (12153): Can't elaborate top-level user hierarchy

I also understand that it doesn't like the `rising_edge(toggle)` but I need that in order to make the LED pattern light up and disappear.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity FP is
    port(
    clk, reset : in std_logic;
    QF : out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    checkbtn : in std_logic;
    Switch : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    sel : in std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
    score : out std_logic_vector (6 downto 0)

    );
end FP;

architecture behavior of FP is

signal time_count: integer:=0;
signal toggle : std_logic;
signal toggle1 : std_logic;
signal count : std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
signal seg : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
signal compare : integer range 0 to 1:=0;
type STATE_TYPE is (level1, level2);
signal level : STATE_TYPE;    
--signal input : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
--signal sev : std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);
begin

process (clk, reset, sel)
    begin
        if (reset = '0') then
            time_count <= 0;
            toggle <= '0';
        elsif rising_edge (clk) then
            case sel is
            when "00" =>
                if (time_count = 1249999) then
                        toggle <= not toggle;
                        time_count <= 0;
                    else
                        time_count <= time_count+1;
                    end if;            
            when "01" =>
                if (time_count = 2499999) then
                    toggle1 <= not toggle1;
                    time_count <= 0;
                else
                    time_count <= time_count+1;
                    end if;
            when "10" =>
                if (time_count = 4999999) then
                    toggle <= not toggle;
                    time_count <= 0;
                else
                    time_count <= time_count+1;
                    end if;
            when "11" =>
                if (time_count = 12499999) then
                    toggle <= not toggle;
                    time_count <= 0;
                else
                    time_count <= time_count+1;
                end if;
            end case;
        end if;
    end process;



Process (toggle, compare, switch)
    begin                

    case level is
    when level1 =>
        if sel = "00" then
            count <= "001"; 
            seg <= "1000";
        elsif (rising_edge (toggle)) then
            count <= "001";
            compare <= 0;
            if (count = "001") then
                count <= "000";
            else
            count <= "000";
            end if;
        end if;

        if (switch = "1000") and (compare = 0) and (checkbtn <= '0') then
            score <= "1111001";
            level <= level2;
        else
            score <= "1000000";
            level <= level1;
        end if;

    when level2 =>
        if sel = "01" then
            count <= "010";
            seg <= "0100";
        elsif (rising_edge (toggle1)) then
            count <= "010";
            compare <= 1;
            if (count = "010") then
                count <= "000";
            else
            count <= "000";
            end if;
        end if;

        if (switch = "0100") and (compare = 1) and (checkbtn <= '0') then
            score <= "0100100";
        else
            score <= "1000000";
            level <= level1;
        end if;
    end case;


    case count is
        when "000"=>seg<="0000";
        when "001"=>seg<="1000";
        when "010"=>seg<="0100";
        when "011"=>seg<="0110";
        when "100"=>seg<="0011";
        when others=>seg<="0000";
    end case;    
end process;


QF <= seg;
end behavior;
```

Thanks again in advance!

Comment: I fixed your layout in the previous edit, but you reverted that... I have no idea why you did that, but this is a waste of my time...

Comment: I edited my question because it is slightly different before. I had written another question but I was asked to edit my old one so I did. Sorry

Comment: Oh, just get ability to comment:) So I edited your post. It is VERY important to have properly intended code. I will post edit to my answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

Well... it is hard to tell what is wrong, because this state machine is written in wrong way. You should look for references about proper modeling of FSM in VHDL. One good example is [here](http://vhdlguru.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-implement-state-machines-in-vhdl.html).
If you use Quartus, you could also look for Altera's description on how to model FSM specifically for their compiler.

I will now give you just two advices. First is that you shouldn't (or mabye even you can't) use is two

```
if rising_edge (clk)
```

checks in one process. If your process is supposed to be sensitive on clock edge, write it once at the beginning.

Second thing is that if you want to model FSM with one process with synchronous reset, then put just clk on sensitivity list.

EDIT after question and code edit:

Ok, much better now. But another few things:

1. Your FSM is still not like it should. Look again at the example in the source I gave you above and edit it to be like there, or make it one process FSM like in example in this [link](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/implementing-a-finite-state-machine-in-vhdl/).
2. Intends! Very important. I couldn't spot some of obvious errors, before I made proper intendation in your code. This leads me to...
3. Look at the places, there you assign values to count, in particular the if statements. No mater what, you assign the same value of "000".
4. Similar story with another signal - seg. You assign to it some value in the process, and then at the end of this process there is case statement in which you assign to it some other value, making this previous assignments irrelevant.
5. Use rising_edge only once in the process, only to clock, and only at the very beginning of the process, or in the way you did in the first process, that has asynchronous reset. In second process you did all this three things.
6. In sequential process with rising_edge, like the first one, you don't have to put to sensitivity list anything more than clock, and reset if it is asynchronous, like in your case.
7. Sensitivity list in second process. It is parallel process, so you should put there signals, that you check in a process, and can change outside of it. It is not the case for compare. But there should be signals: level, sel and toggle1.

As I'm still not sure what are you trying to achieve, I will not tell you what exactly to do. Fix your code according to points above, then maybe it will just work.

Comment: Thank you! The only reason I had 2 clocks was because I wanted to change the speed of the counter at each level. I have moved the clock to the outside of the FSM and it still did not like it, but I will try to fix the state machine. Thanks again

Comment: If this answer satisfy you,  please accept it.  Thanks:) if you still have problems after fixing machine,  modify your question with  new code and I will look at it.

Comment: I know how to build a basic FSM but in order for the "SIMON" aspect of it to work, I need different clocks for different levels and I'm not really sure how to approach that. I need the next case to have a different seg because I want there to be a new LED pattern for the next level. Also, I need some way for the light to turn on and turn off, and that was what toggle was for, so I'm not really sure how to get it to toggle on and then off automatically. Not sure if this makes any sense but let me know!

Comment: If you try to model FSM in wrong way, it will not work. This is for sure.
I can't help you much more, because I still don't understand what are you trying to achieve. Describe your inputs, outputs, and signals better, and elaborate on description of what do you want to do (I know what Simon game is, but have no idea how this is connected to what I see in your code)